# Flutter accessing a local variable from statefulwidget

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, navigation-drawer

I am building an app that has a login page and a homepage so far. I can sign in with google and can be redirected to the current page(Homepage). I have a display name and an email address that is the output of the login page. I want to use these details to be displayed in my drawer. Is there a way to access those variables from the login page and use them on the homepage as well.

Here is my google sign in function.

```
Future  <String> signInWithGoogle() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken, idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,);
  final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

  assert(!user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

  final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
  assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
  print("signed in " + user.displayName);
  print("signed in " + user.email);
  return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
}
```

I logged in using my Gmail and got the output as.

```
I/flutter (15019): signed in Shero thehero
I/flutter (15019): signed in aakashsrh@gmail.com
```

Here is my homepage code.

```
class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {

  TextEditingController _searchController =TextEditingController();
  Future signOutGoogle() async{
    await googleSignIn.signOut();
    print("User Sign Out");
  }

  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  TextEditingController _searchController =TextEditingController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      }
```

while in the app I get the output NULL while I run the following code.

```
new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: Text("${user?.displayName}"),
                accountEmail: Text('user?.email'),
                currentAccountPicture: GestureDetector(
                  child:new CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                    child: Icon(Icons.person,color: Colors.white,),
                  ),
                ),
```

[here is the output for the code in my drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjibI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `user = authResult.user` should be in a call to `setState()`.

So:

```
setState((){
    user = authResult.user
})
```

Without that the widget doesn't know that/when `user` has changed, so doesn't know when to repaint.

Comment: This certainly resolved my problem.